# Sublime Text 3 multiple selection across several layouts

Tags: windows, sublimetext3, hotkeys

Is there any way how we could select the same part of file across several layouts

(as like `ctrl + d` in a single document)?

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, no. You can only have one view active (accepting input) at a time, so key combinations are only effective on one file at a time. Of course, a plugin could be written to search and select a certain region across all open views or windows, if you know Python.